# Pull and update data from database in PHP CodeIgniter foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, foreach

I have a view which contains the data which is displayed from the database by a foreach loop and i want is to get the data which is edited from the view and update it in the database one by one but the problem is that database will be updated if there is a where clause but in my case i don't know how to get the key(tid) from view to controller here is the controller function which displays the data

```
public function bulk()
{

    $pid = '';
    if($this->input->post('pid'))
        $pid = $this->input->post('pid');


    $template['menu'] = $this->shared_model->get_flightmenus();

    if($pid == '')
    {
        if($this->uri->segment(3))
            $pid = $this->uri->segment(3);
        else
            $pid = $template['menu'][0]['tid'];
    }

    $template['pid'] = $pid;

    // echo $pid;
    // exit();

    $template['airline'] = $this->shared_model->get_records('eat_airline');
    $template['terminal'] = $this->shared_model->get_records('eat_terminal');

    $template['data'] = $this->shared_model->get_recordbyvalue('eat_flight','menu_tid = '.$pid);

    $template['main_content'] = $this->load->view('flight/flight_bulk_view', $template, true);
    $this->load->view('includes/template', $template);



}
```

here is the view

```
    <h4><?php echo anchor('login/logout', 'Logout'); ?></h4>
<?php echo anchor('/home', 'Home'); ?>/Flights
<h2>Flights</h2>
    <div>
    <?php echo form_open('/flight/') ?>
    <?php foreach($menu as $row){ $options[$row['tid']] = $row['m_name']; } ?>
    <?php $js = 'name="pid" id="pid" onChange="this.form.submit();"'; ?>
    <?php echo form_dropdown('pid', $options, $pid, $js); ?>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
    </div>
<?php echo anchor('/flight/display/1/0/'.$pid, 'Create'); ?>
<?php echo anchor('flight/bulk', 'Bulk Update'); ?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Name
        </td>
        <td>
            Airline
        </td>
        <td>
            From
        </td>
        <td>
            Stopover
        </td>
        <td>
            Destination
        </td>
        <td>
            Price
        </td>
        <td>
            Unit
        </td>
        <td>
            Tax
        </td>
        <td>
            Protection
        </td>
        <td>
            Fare
        </td>
        <td>
            Week Offer
        </td>
        <td>
            Menu
        </td>
        <td>
            Sort
        </td>
        <td>
            Edit
        </td>
        <td>
            Delete
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach($data as $row){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php echo $row['f_name'] ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php $options1[0] = ''; foreach($airline as $row1){ $options[$row1['tid']] = $row1['a_name']; } ?>
            <?php echo $options[$row['airline_tid']]; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php $options1[0] = ''; foreach($terminal as $row1){ $options[$row1['tid']] = $row1['t_name']; } ?>
            <?php echo $options[$row['terminal_from_tid']]; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $row['t_stopover'] ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php $options1[0] = ''; foreach($terminal as $row1){ $options[$row1['tid']] = $row1['t_name']; } ?>
            <?php echo $options[$row['terminal_destination_tid']]; ?>
        </td>

        <td>
            <?php echo $row['f_price'] ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $row['f_unit'] ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php if($row['f_tax']>0) echo  'Yes'; else echo 'No'; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $row['f_protection'] ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $row['f_fare'] ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php if($row['f_weekoffer']>0) echo  'Yes'; else echo 'No'; ?>
        </td>
        <!--
        <td>
            <?php $options[0] = ''; foreach($menu as $row1){ $options[$row1['tid']] = $row1['m_name']; } ?>
            <?php echo $options[$row['menu_tid']]; ?>
        </td>
        -->
        <td>
            <?php echo $row['sortindex'] ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo anchor('flight/display/2/'.$row['tid'].'/'.$pid, 'Edit'); ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo anchor('flight/display/3/'.$row['tid'].'/'.$pid, 'Delete'); ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

i am unable to come up with the logic of how it will be done

> any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all i can see is that you want to pass the data from your view to controller you can do that by passing your data to url and then use it from the controller for future use.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting values from DB row by row. Each row in your database has a unique ID (hopefully). That is your main criteria for the WHERE clause.

I don't see any inputs in your HTML, so I don't really understand how you are saving the data, but you can either do a hidden input in each row like `<input type="hidden" id="[your_row_id_from_DB]" />` or if you have multiple inputs per row - add a name with id appended to it, like `<input type="text" name="flight_your_row_id" />` . That way you can parse your names and know which values are submitted.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have managed this through the url function but now the problem is how can i update them all at the same time or with a foreach loop? 
<?php echo anchor('flight/bulk_update/'.$row['tid'].'/'.$row['f_price'], 'Update All'); ?>